# How to change order of Date of Birth Fields in CakePHP 3 Form

Tags: date, cakephp, datefield, cakephp-3.3

I am comparatively new to CakePHP3. I am creating a form with a Date of Birth field in it, with **dob** field name.

```
echo $this->Form->input('dob',['label'=>'Date of Birth']);
```

Fields are rendered in Year - Month - Day sequence. I want it be rendered in Day - Month - Year sequence. I have been checking the CakePHP3 documentation for sometime now but I am not able to change the order of the date fields. Here is how it is rendered:

[image]

Please guide me. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

Oh I found it [here](http://api.cakephp.org/3.2/class-Cake.View.Helper.FormHelper.html#%24_defaultConfig), in the [FormHelper API documentation](http://api.cakephp.org/3.2/class-Cake.View.Helper.FormHelper.html#%24_defaultConfig)! There is dateWidget template in 'templates' which one can use to change the default sequence of date fields. For example I had to do like this:

```
echo $this->Form->input('dob',['label'=>'Date of Birth', 'templates' => ['dateWidget' => '{{day}}{{month}}{{year}}']]);
```